# Update the latest record in the duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have products table and I have duplicate records in the table according to `product_code`. Instead of deleting the old record I need to update the old record and keep the latest record as it. So here are how they look like in the table

```
id      product_code    Qty     Type    updatedDate                 addedDate
1       AB12            5       AB      2017-05-11 09:00:00         2017-05-11 09:00:00
2       CD12            4       AC      2016-05-11 09:00:00         2016-05-11 09:00:00     
3       EF12            5       AB      2016-05-11 09:00:00         2016-05-11 09:00:00
4       AB12            6       AB      2016-05-11 09:00:00         2016-05-11 09:00:00
5       GH12            5       AC      2016-05-11 09:00:00         2016-05-11 09:00:00
6       IJ12            6       AB      2016-05-11 09:00:00         2016-05-11 09:00:00
7       KL12            8       AB      2016-05-11 09:00:00         2016-05-11 09:00:00
8       EF12            10      AB      2017-05-11 09:00:00         2017-05-11 09:00:00
9       GH12            1       AC      2017-05-11 09:00:00         2017-05-11 09:00:00
10      MN12            3       AB      2016-05-11 09:00:00         2016-05-11 09:00:00
```

For all the old records according to `addedDate`, I need to set `Qty` to '0'.

I selected the records from the following query but I need to update them with latest record. Here is the query

```
SELECT id, product_code, Qty, Type, updatedDate, addedDate 
FROM products WHERE Type = 'AB'
GROUP BY `product_code`
HAVING COUNT(`product_code`) > 1 ORDER BY `products`.`addedDate`
```

Answer (score 2):

With a self join:

```
update tablename t
inner join tablename tt 
on tt.product_code = t.product_code and tt.addedDate > t.addedDate
set t.qty = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nSspCd5GRxKQ5GQerS6DMX/0).

Comment: I like this answer it is concise +1.

Comment: I ran this query, and I don't why It hanged my server :(

Comment: Yes, it's concise, but it might not scale so well. Plus, I wonder if the sample data set is over-simplified.

Comment: I updated my question and added selected query for which I need to update records

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET Qty = 0
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
            WHERE t2.product_code = t1.product_code AND t2.id <> t1.id) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.addedDate < t1.addedDate);
```

The first exists clause ensures that the `product_id` occurs more than once, i.e. that this record is a "duplicate" as you have defined it.  The second exists clause ensures that we cannot find any other older record in the duplicate set, implying that a matching record is the oldest.  If both conditions be true, then we update the quantity to zero.

Comment: I receive this following error -> Syntax error near 'WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM

Comment: @AkaashK Please try the updated answer, I had a slight typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea...

```
update tablename t
  LEFT 
  join
     ( SELECT MAX(id) id FROM tablename GROUP BY product_code ) x
    ON x.id = t.id
   set t.qty = 0
 WHERE x.id IS NULL;
```

Setting a temporary column to the old qty values, then setting all old qty values to zero, then executing (an inner join on) the inverse of the above has the potential to be faster.